# How to create a tabed form in prestashop admin menu

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

Does any one know how to create a tabed menu form  in Prestashop admin side [image]

I want to add tabs when the Health Check Configuration menu is clicked .
Need to show Tabs such as Checks, Support Groups.. etc
In the above section I want to add a tabbed menu as shown below in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom module for all code, in `install()` function create a new `Tab` for menu link (check how to do it in `classes/Tab.php`), use `HelperOptions` class for tabs in page content (check i. e. `controllers/admin/AdminThemesController.php`).

As in this code:

```
$this->fields_options = array(
    'appearance' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Your title'),
        'icon' => 'icon-html5',
        'tabs' => array(
            'logo' => $this->l('Logo'),
            'logo2' => $this->l('Invoice & Email Logos'),
            'icons' => $this->l('Icons'),
            'mobile' => $this->l('Mobile'),
            ),
        'fields' => array(
            'PS_LOGO' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Header logo'),
            'hint' => $this->l('Will appear on main page. Recommended height: 52px. Maximum height on default theme: 65px.'),
            'type' => 'file',
            'name' => 'PS_LOGO',
            'tab' => 'logo',
            'thumb' => _PS_IMG_.Configuration::get('PS_LOGO')
           ),
    /.../ ));
```

[image: Tabs example.]

When you define `type` it becames a part of code which you can check in `your-site-admin/themes/default/template/helpers/options/options.tpl`. There are code lines like `$field['type'] == 'select' /.../` etc. which depends on your `type` defined.

Comment: I am talking about the  top tab in a form display not the left side tab (menu tab)

Comment: now  i want to display a grid in the tab how to do this??

Comment: Use `$this->fields_list = array(/.../);` and `HelperList` class: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperList+class

Comment: ya ya i did that but how to call it correctly ie how to add to that to my tab ,
Also what type I should  write for the field and how to assign the $this->fields_list to that type??

Comment: Check the documentation link above. Also you can find the example in Prestashop back office pages which is more or less similar to what you need and copy that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I Added and managed by your hint and  help thank you very much 
below is the code what i did :

```
$this->fields_options = array(
'appearance' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Manage  your Health Check '),
    'icon' => 'icon-html5',
    'tabs' => array(
        'TAB1' => $this->l('SUPPORT_GROUPS'),
        'TAB2' => $this->l('CHECKS'),
        'TAB3' => $this->l('REPORT RECIPIENTS'),
        ),
    'fields' => array(
        'SUPPORT_GROUPS' => array(

        'tab' => 'TAB1'
       ),
       'CHECKS' => array(

        'tab' => 'TAB2'
       ),
         'REPORT_RECIPIENTS' => array(

        'tab' => 'TAB3'
       ),

 ) ));
```